# String conversion in hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a json string in which there isa field called version.
Version can either not be there or if it is there it will be of form x.y
.

I want to convert this to x.0 I am currently doing

> CONCAT(split(get_json_object(json, '$.version'),'[.]')[0],".","0")

but this does not handle cases where version is not there.

I want "bad_version" to be returned if version is not there. Can I somehow use COALESCE and do some tweaks ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use either `COALESCE` or `CASE` - the syntax is identical to database usage.

```
select coalesce(myField, 'bad_version') ....
```

or

```
select case when myField is null then 'bad_version' else myField end as x ....
```

Comment: the split will throw error when version is not there right ?

Comment: It shouldn't do: I can issue `select split(null, '-') ...` and it doesn't throw any exceptions (Hive 0.10) - it returns `null`. I don't know about the function `get_json_object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally test the result of `get_json_object` to see if it's `NULL` and return `bad_version` accordingly.  When the version is valid, you can use a regular expression to replace the minor version with `0`.

```
SELECT
  IF(get_json_object(json, "$.version") IS NULL,
    "bad_version",
    regexp_replace(get_json_object(json, "$.version") , "\\..*$", ".0")
  )
FROM json_table;  -- The table I loaded with test data
```

Some simple example data:

```
hive> SELECT json FROM json_table;
OK
{"id":"001","version":"3.9"}
{"id":"002","notversion":"3.9"}
Time taken: 0.225 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

And then the results of this query against this data:

```
hive> SELECT
    >   IF(get_json_object(json, "$.version") IS NULL,
    >     "bad_version",
    >     regexp_replace(get_json_object(json, "$.version") , "\\..+$", ".0")   
    >   )   
    > FROM json_table;
OK
3.0
bad_version
Time taken: 0.225 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```